# Extract text between two line numbers

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I am trying to extract the text between two specific line numbers using

```
sed 'startLine,endLined' myFile.txt
```

But somehow it keeps extracting from the begining of the file to endLine.

What is wrong here?

Comment: you need to use `-n` option and `p` command.. for ex: `seq 25 34 | sed -n '6,9p'`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to tell sed not to print all other lines but the ones you want.

```
 sed -n '123,234p' myFile.txt
```

The -n tells sed do not print lines scanned.
the 123,234 define the range of lines you are interested in
the p is the command to print the line.

This way it will only print the lines that match what you told it.

Comment: Thank you, works like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

Try `sed -n 'startLine,endLined' myFile.txt`

Comment: Please add explanation to your answer

Answer (score 1):

Another using awk:

```
$ seq 10 -1 1 | awk 'NR==3,NR==6'
8
7
6
5
```

`seq 10 -1 1` outputs numbers from 10 down to 1. `awk 'NR==3,NR==6'` prints records between lines 3-6.